# A BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER can cause MUTATING TABLE Oracle error?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Please suppose you have, in Oracle Database, a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER`.

If fires only when in a particular column is assigned a certain value (in example, the string `'SUBSTITUTE`'` is inserted as update in the ALPHA column), otherwise it does not fire.

This trigger does many queries and, under certain conditions, updates some records of the triggered table.

Being a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER`, could it cause `MUTATING TABLE` error?

You can assume that the body of the trigger does not update the ALPHA column, but could update other columns and/or insert new records in the same table, using `:OLD` values.

The update of the `ALPHA` column to the string value `'SUBSTITUTE'` provokes the trigger fire.

Comment: Why would you want a trigger to update records in the table it's against? That's pretty much the definition of a mutating table. Both the 'does many queries' part and the update suggest that perhaps a trigger is not the right tool here; this is quite vague though, and what the right tool is depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Alex Poole, if you transform your comment in an answer, I can of course accept it!

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-for-mutating-table-errors/5439#5439

It's a classical case of mutating table Oracle error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [mutating table is a table that is currently being modified by an update, delete, or insert statement](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Mutating_table). If your before-update for-each-row trigger tries to modify the table that is defined against then it will get an `ORA-04091: table X is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` error. [Here's a SQL Fiddle with a trivial example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25ace/1).

You'd get the same [with an after-update trigger](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73656/1) depending on what you're doing; and you can't make it statement-level if you need to act depending on the `:new.alpha` value.

Both the 'does many queries' part and the update suggest that perhaps a trigger is not the right tool here; this is quite vague though, and what the right tool is depends on what you're doing. A procedure that makes all the necessary changes and is called instead of the simple update might be one solution, for example.